# How to turn on IDENTITY_INSERT with EF in .NET Core

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am building a React web app using .NET Core api and Entity Framework connected to Azure database. The issue is when I try to add a new item through the api's http, I get this error:

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Most of the solutions I found were to add `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` in the context's file to the id column or add this line of code in my Model (above the ID)

```
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
```

However, none of the solutions worked. Any advices would be appreciated as currently I have no clue how to change that settings without using sql.

Here is also my HttpPost method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateProduct")]
        public void AddProduct(Product p)
        {
            ProductHandler _handler = new ProductHandler();
            _handler.CreateProduct(p);
        }
```

and the handler:

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
    ApplicationDbContext context;
    using (context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var listOfProducts = context.Products;
        products.Clear();
        foreach (Product product in listOfProducts)
        {
            products.Add(product);
        }
        context.Dispose();
    }
    return products;
}

public void CreateProduct(Product p)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {

        context.Products.Add(p);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Comment: The essential part is what happens in `_handler.CreateProduct(p)`.

Comment: @GertArnold Nothing too crazy, but I have updated my post including the code from there

Comment: That handler looks deeply dubious. A database context should be treated roughly as a unit of work, you shouldn't be creating and disposing of one for each separate database operation. The `GetProducts `method also looks wrong, in that `products` seems to be scoped outside of this one method for no readily apparent reason, leading to potential unwanted sharing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as someone who is learning I am sure there are lots of mistakes that I am making, but in this case I really don't know how else I am supposed to code it?

Comment: You probably just try to insert a Product having an Id > 0.

Comment: @GertArnold That was indeed the problem lol, I don't know why I didn't try it. I also have one more problem with EF - uploading a picture to the product. I have this property   `[NotMapped] public IFormFile FileUri { get; set; }` but when I upload the picture in the api, the database saves null as an entry. Any idea what the problem could be there?

Comment: No idea, ask a new question with the essential code. Finally, just a tip, don't trust input coming from an API endpoint (or UI). Create entities in the backend and communicate through DTO objects. You wouldn't have had this error (or have more easily spotted it) if there was a `new Product()` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises when you pass an ID to the backend server, which should not be done. Entity Framework is configured to automatically generate a unique ID for each entity by using the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute. Therefore, you need to ensure that the ID remains at its default value, typically 0, when adding a new entity to the database, allowing EF Core to correctly handle and generate a unique ID for it.

You could create web api app and use test code as follow

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ProductsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        
        _context.Products.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }

    
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return product;
    }
}
```